# Display dynamically embbeded pdf as image with excel function

Tags: excel, object, pdf, excel-formula

i have a file with multiple embbeded pdf. (hidden tab)
i would like to do a dropdown list for user to select a "key" and this should display the related pdf as an image.

i dont manage to find how to link my key and the pdf in order to be able to display to the user the right pdf.
and in best of world would be to directly display the pdf as an image inside the excel.

example :
i select key1, it finds the related pdf-key1 in another hidden tab and display it as an image.

i would like to avoid using VBA for this.

thanks in advance

i tried vlookup, but object seems not linked to a cell so nothing found.
i dont understand how to retrieve an object from formula.

Comment: You need to at least share some sample data and examples of what you edxpect from that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.